# How to show the following result in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $a^2=b^2+c^2$, where $b, c\in \mathbb{Z}^\setminus\{0\}$. Then $a$ cannot be written as

1. $pd^2$, where $d\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime with $p\equiv 1\ \text{mod}\ 4$.
2. $pd^2$, where $d\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime with $p\equiv 3\ \text{mod}\ 4$.

How to show that option 1 is incorrect but second is correct.

I know that modulo $4$, sum of any number is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. But don't get how to apply this result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, you can just show an example, like $5^2=3^2+4^2$

For 2, the fact that all squares are $0$ or $1 \bmod 4$ is what you want.  If $d$ is odd, the left side is equivalent to $3 \bmod 4$, while the right is $0,1,$ or $2 \bmod 4$.  If $d$ is even, the left side is $0 \bmod 4$, so both $b$ and $c$ are even.  If there are any solutions to the equation, there is one with the smallest left side.  If $d$ is even, we can divide all of $b,c,d$ by $2$ and have another solution.  Keep going until $d$ is odd, then apply that case.

Comment: In your example for $1^{st}$ option, $a=5^{1 \over 2}$ which is not an integer.

Comment: @JayantJha:  Thanks, fixed.