# multiple choice question on number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $a=b^2+c^2$ where, $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. Then $a$ cannot be written as

1. $pd^2$ where $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime with $p \equiv 1 \pmod4$
2. $pd^2$ where $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime with $p \equiv 3\pmod4$
3. $pqd^2$ where $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p,q$ are primes with $p \equiv 1\pmod4$ and $q \equiv 3\pmod4$
4. $pqd^2$ where $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p,q$ are primes with $p,q \equiv 3\pmod4$

The similar question with some part missing is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342086/how-to-show-the-following-result-in-number-theory), but I want to discuss additional options too.

Here, I got 1) is false Since $13=3^2+2^2$
For other options What should I do

Comment: Use `$\pmod{4}$` for $\pmod{4}$.

Comment: I am confused by your counterexample to (1). You are using d=5 and p=1, but 1 is not prime.

Comment: Your answer to $1)$,  doesn't appear to me to work, because $\ 5^2\ $ is *not* of the form $\ pd^2\ $ with $\ d\in\mathbb{Z}\ $ and $\ p\ $ prime.

Comment: thanks for comment, I corrected and given another  example for 1 is false

Comment: This is clearly a pop quiz to whether you have memorize the "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem" Sum of Two Squares theorem and are capable or rattling it off whenever you see a sum of two primes. If you have it memorized you are fine.  Otherwise you can derive and prove it for yourself in three minutes while under pressure....

Comment: The [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342086/how-to-show-the-following-result-in-number-theory) cited in the post is about the equation $\ a^2=b^2+c^2\ $, whereas this one has $\ a=b^2+c^2\ $.  Is the missing exponent on the $\ a\ $ here an *intentional* difference, or a typo?

Comment: my question correct version is with $a$ alone. no squres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can conclude like this, by [Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) options,  2,3,4 are the correct options. For first option we  have counter example, 5=$1^2+2^2$.

Answer (score 0):

(2) Is correct since we know that every sum of two squares must be divisible by primes of the form $4n+1$ or of the form $4n+3$ if they are raised to an even exponent.
Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) for more details.

Comment: Isn't 4) also correct (assuming $p\ne q$.

Comment: Of course not. The product will be $\equiv 1\p mod{4}$ but not the sum of two squares.$

Comment: Huh???? and $a$ *is* the sum of two squares.  So contains no primes $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ to an odd power.  If $a = pqd^2$ then $a$ has *two* such primes.  So $a=pqd^2 \ne b^2 + c^2$.

Comment: By "correct" we mean can not be true.  2 and 4 can not be sum of two squares.  1 and 3 both can be and are.

Comment: Yes but it does not say that $p \neq q$. So, this is the "most" correct answer.

Comment: .. it does say prime***s***. Course, one can say prime*s* mean instances of primes and they can be instances of the same prime. But one can just as legitimately claim that there is one one $7$ and every occurrence of $7$ is the *same* $7$ as there is only one $7$ in the universe. And one can also claim they never said "prime" was meant in the mathematical sense and maybe they meant the best quality you can buy in a market. We've reached to point of absurdity. But I think claiming 4) is def. wrong be is doesn't specify specify $p\ne q$ is less valid then claiming it is right bec. is implies so.